# How to render text in the DataGridComboBoxColumn, in read mode of the row

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a data grid, with a Combo Box column, defined as:

```
                <!-- Category -->
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedCategory}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName">
                    <!-- Display mode -->
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding SelectedCategoryDisplayName}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>

                    <!-- Edit mode -->
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Transaction.Type}" Value="Debit">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource debitCategories}}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Transaction.Type}" Value="Credit">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource creditCategories}}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

It is backed by the View Model property:

```
    public string SelectedCategoryDisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return "something";
        }
    }
```

In the designer, this is giving me the following error:

```
A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'SelectedCategoryDisplayName' of type XXX
```

Why? Why does WPF care that the property is read-only, when it is used in the `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle`. If I understand correctly, `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle` is the style for the read mode of the cell.

Ok, so I have set `,Mode=OneWay` on the binding and it stopped complaining, but it's not showing anything.

How do I make the Combo Box show text provided by my View Model, in the read mode (non-edit) of the cell/row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why? Why does WPF care that the property is read-only, when it is used in the DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle.

Because you are binding to the Text property of the ComboBox and this property is two-way by default. Either the source property must have a public setter or you need to set the Mode of the binding to OneWay.

> How do I make the Combo Box show text provided by my View Model, in the read mode (non-edit) of the cell/row?

Try this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCategoryDisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the code snippet does not work. Indeed `SelectedCategoryDisplayName` belongs to the `T`. And I can see it in the debugger being called. But the UI still displays NOTHING in place of where the text block is supposed to be. Could the `<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedCategory}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName">` be messing with it?

Comment: Once again - my savior ;)

Comment: Strange side effect - the combo box does not want to enter in Edit mode now ... It must be because we have completely overridden its View mode and now "doesn't know" how to enter Edit mode.

Comment: Replace the ComboBox with a DataGridTemplateColumn then. Same functionality - much more flexible. It's either this or simply displaying the property specififed by the SelectedValueBinding property.